# Skybox Renders in Unity but anything else doesn't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render

sorry if the solution is quite obvious but I'm still a learning student.
I'm teaching myself on the side by making a 2D game and was working with Unity but got stuck when I noticed the Game screen and the Camera Preview display the game properly, but the moment I run it, it only shows the Skybox and nothing else in front of that... The Main Camera is behind the Background so I'm a lil confused why it only renders the Skybox.. any advice?

I put some pics below as an example of the settings (yes the camera follows the player and some usages are a bit outdated)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mind showing us your camera follow script?

Comment: just gonna throw this out there but I have a suspicion that when you are updating the camera position you are possibly setting it's z to 0.  If so then that is why it works in the preview and not when you launch it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I added the script for the following camera. I put boundaries in the main camera which hold the script to a max and minimum value to where it can move, besides that, it keeps the player roughly in the middle of the screen. It might indeed be the case that the camera position in the Z is moving as wel but I thought it would stay stationary like this? 
Even if I remove the Z transform, it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Are you certain the player object is found by the time that start is called?  if not you may have an error in your log

Comment: It should do, I have the player in a different "Player" layer in front of everything, I put a picture up as reference but may I ask where the error log is so I can review it, as it doesn't show up when I run it

Comment: on the bottom of unity there where you see your asset list there should be a button to see the console, that is where you would see the error, just because the player is in front of everything doesnt mean it is loaded first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After another look, and close inspection, I would like to point you at where your objects are actually located, your max and min for your camera is: -4 and 0.66 your BG and your camera are starting at -100 something.  so when the game starts your camera is moving to -4 from -110 that is why you cannot see them.

Comment: Shaking my head... how could I overlook such a stupid thing.. that was indeed the issue, thanks a lot for the patience and effort!